# \ex with parbox causing example number to go into margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, expex, parbox

The only difference between the two examples below is that the first one uses `\ex` (which displays an example number) and the second uses `\exdisplay` (no example number). They are otherwise exactly the same.

Both are set in a `parbox` environment. As you can see with `\ex`, the example number lands in the margin and a gap appears between the "text" and the interlinear, as if the whole interlinear gloss was pushed to the right. Why is this happening?

I would like the entire interlinear + example number pushed to the left so that everything is with the margins like the `\exdisplay` example. Messing around with `textoffset` and `numoffset` did not yield the desired effect.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex}
    \lingset{glhangstyle=none}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo Bar}
This one has \verb=\ex=.

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut\textenglish
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\begin{hebrew}\ex\begingl
\gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד ההההה ווווו זזזזז טטטטט //
\glb words words words word words words words words //
\glc words words words words words words words words //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}}}%

\noindent This one has \verb=\exdisplay=.

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut\textenglish
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\begin{hebrew}\exdisplay\begingl
\gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד ההההה ווווו זזזזז טטטטט //
\glb words words words word words words words words //
\glc words words words words words words words words //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257628/121944) to be most helpful. It's not perfect though because the interlinear moves to the second line too soon and leaves a big gap where there should be almost no gap (in my MWE). But for the sake of this question it is close enough.

Additionally, I have emailed the `expex` [creator](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/generic/expex/expex-doc.pdf) to ask him to fix this RTL `\ex` issue, using this MWE as an excellent starting point. Hopefully he has a more complete solution.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex}
    \lingset{glhangstyle=none}

\makeatletter
\def\ex@c{%
   \ex@setup
   \leavevmode
   \setbox\numbox=\hbox{\hskip\lingnumoffset\ep@actualexnoprint}%
   \epd@numright=\wd\numbox
   \ifcase\ep@textanchor                          % numleft
         \ep@settosum\leftskip\lingnumoffset\lingtextoffset
      \or                                         % normal
         \ep@settosum\leftskip\epd@numright\lingtextoffset
      \fi
   % begin changes
   % \llap{\hbox to\leftskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}%
   \if@RTL
     \hbox to\leftskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}%
   \else
     \llap{\hbox to\leftskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}%
   \fi
   % end changes
   \lingeveryex
   \latex@tagex
   \ignorespaces
}

\def\glw@begingl@a{%
   \bgroup
   \parindent0pt
   \ep@setglstrut
   \ifdim\ling@glwidth=0pt
      \ifling@glossbreaking
         \bgroup
       \else
         \vtop\bgroup
           % begin changes
           % \advance\hsize by -\leftskip
           \if@RTL
              \advance\hsize by -2\leftskip
           \else
              \advance\hsize by -\leftskip
           \fi
           % end changes
            \advance\hsize by -\rightskip
            \leftskip=0pt
       \fi
   \else
      \vtop\bgroup
         \hsize=\ling@glwidth
         \leftskip=0pt
   \fi
   \bgroup
   \parindent=0pt
   \@glpreamblefalse
   \@glftfalse
   \let\mainlist=\empty
   \let\itemtypelist=\empty
   \let\aboveskiplist=\empty
   \let\strutlist=\empty
   \let\everylist=\empty
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo Bar}
This one has \verb=\ex=.

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut\textenglish
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\begin{hebrew}\ex\begingl
\gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד ההההה ווווו זזזזז ט //
\glb words words words word words words words w //
\glc words words words words words words words w //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}}}%

\noindent This one has \verb=\exdisplay=.

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut\textenglish
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\begin{hebrew}\exdisplay\noexno\begingl
\gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד ההההה ווווו זזזזז טטטטט //
\glb words words words word words words words words //
\glc words words words words words words words words //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]