# Big gap between two parboxes in modified RTL expex environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, right-to-left, expex, parbox

Below are several sets of identical side-by-side `parbox`es; the right `parbox` contains an interlinear gloss ([`expex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en)) and the left contains regular text. The top three sets are before the [modified `expex` code from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428965/121944), and the bottom set is with the modified code implemented. The modified code simply puts the `example number` on the correct side of the margin in a RTL context (see bottom vs top examples).

Based on the way my `parbox`es are set up, there should be almost no gap between them, but as you can see, there is a large gap between the gloss and text. Even if I modify the size of the `parbox` the gap won't shrink. How can I make the distance between the two `parbox`es function as I want?

My guess as to what's happening is that perhaps the modified `expex` code in the MWE is leaving an empty gap where the `example number` normally would go and the `parbox` isn't allowed to fill it in. But I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\section{Bar of Foo 1}
\textbf{Before \textsf{example number} fix.}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut\textenglish
a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa.
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\begin{hebrew}\ex\begingl
\gla א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא //
\glb a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\glc a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}}}%

\noindent\textbf{Before \textsf{example number} fix - English only, no Hebrew}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut
a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa.
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\ex\begingl
\gla a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\glb a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\glc a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\endgl\xe}}%

\noindent\textbf{Before \textsf{example number} fix - English only, no example number. PROPER parbox SPACING}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut
a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa.
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\exdisplay\noexno\begingl
\gla a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\glb a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\glc a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\endgl\xe}}%    

\makeatletter
\def\ex@c{%
   \ex@setup
   \leavevmode
   \setbox\numbox=\hbox{\hskip\lingnumoffset\ep@actualexnoprint}%
   \epd@numright=\wd\numbox
   \ifcase\ep@textanchor                          % numleft
         \ep@settosum\leftskip\lingnumoffset\lingtextoffset
      \or                                         % normal
         \ep@settosum\leftskip\epd@numright\lingtextoffset
      \fi
   % begin changes
   % \llap{\hbox to\leftskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}%
   \if@RTL
     \hbox to\leftskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}%
   \else
     \llap{\hbox to\leftskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}%
   \fi
   % end changes
   \lingeveryex
   \latex@tagex
   \ignorespaces
}

\def\glw@begingl@a{%
   \bgroup
   \parindent0pt
   \ep@setglstrut
   \ifdim\ling@glwidth=0pt
      \ifling@glossbreaking
         \bgroup
       \else
         \vtop\bgroup
           % begin changes
           % \advance\hsize by -\leftskip
           \if@RTL
              \advance\hsize by -2\leftskip
           \else
              \advance\hsize by -\leftskip
           \fi
           % end changes
            \advance\hsize by -\rightskip
            \leftskip=0pt
       \fi
   \else
      \vtop\bgroup
         \hsize=\ling@glwidth
         \leftskip=0pt
   \fi
   \bgroup
   \parindent=0pt
   \@glpreamblefalse
   \@glftfalse
   \let\mainlist=\empty
   \let\itemtypelist=\empty
   \let\aboveskiplist=\empty
   \let\strutlist=\empty
   \let\everylist=\empty
}
\makeatother

\noindent \textbf{After \textsf{example number} fix.}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut\textenglish
a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa.
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\begin{hebrew}\ex\begingl
\gla א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא //
\glb a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\glc a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}}}%    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `\leftskip` is used to leave space for the number, but in RTL typesetting the skip is needed on the right.

You can define a `\beginskip`, which is `\rightskip` or `\leftskip` depending on the direction and use this instead:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\section{Bar of Foo 1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\beginskip{\if@RTL\rightskip\else\leftskip\fi}% added macro 
\def\ex@c{%
   \ex@setup
   \leavevmode
   \setbox\numbox=\hbox{\hskip\lingnumoffset\ep@actualexnoprint}%
   \epd@numright=\wd\numbox
   % begin changes: replace every `\leftskip` with `\beginskip`
   \ifcase\ep@textanchor                          % numleft
        \ep@settosum\beginskip\lingnumoffset\lingtextoffset
      \or                                         % normal
        \ep@settosum\beginskip\epd@numright\lingtextoffset
      \fi
   \llap{\hbox to\beginskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}%
   % end changes
   \lingeveryex
   \latex@tagex
   \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\noindent \textbf{After \textsf{example number} fix.}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{
\exdisplay\noexno\strut\textenglish
a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa.
\xe}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.69\textwidth}{\begin{hebrew}\ex\begingl
\gla א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא א אא אאא //
\glb a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\glc a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa a aa aaa //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}}}%    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much more elegant than the original, partial solution. Would you please comment the line `\def\beginskip{\if@RTL\rightskip\else\leftskip\fi}` so that we know that is also new?